# Should Process.fork affect file io in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, fork

I have been using `Process.fork` within an observable object, but have found that it is interfering with the output from an observer object's file output.

When I comment out the `Process` lines, the file that is output contains 16 lines each in order numbered 0-15.  However, when uncommented the file contains 136 lines of unordered numbers between 0-15.  Whether `Process` is commented out or not, the correct numbers are printed to screen.

Is this behaviour partially expected, or is this a bug?  Has anyone got any ideas how to get around this?

*The code below reproduces the problem and was created by stripping back the original code until there was just enough to demonstrate the issue.  The original reason for using `Process.fork` was to create several processes to speed up processing.*

```ruby
require 'observer'

class Recorder
  def initialize(notifier, filename)
    notifier.add_observer(self)
    @save_file =  File.open(filename, 'w')
    @i = 0
  end

  def update
    puts @i
    @save_file.puts @i
    @i += 1
  end


  def stop
    @save_file.close
  end
end


class Notifier
  include Observable

  def run
    16.times do 
      # When the following two Process lines are uncommented,
      # the file output from the Recorder above is erratic
      Process.fork {exit}
      Process.wait

      changed
      notify_observers
    end
  end
end


notifier = Notifier.new
recorder = Recorder.new(notifier, 'test.data')

notifier.run
recorder.stop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you fork, the child process will contain a clone of the parent's open File, with whatever data is pending in its buffer. When the child exits it will flush this data and close its open file.  This doesn't effect the parent's or siblings' open files, but since they all map to the same kernel fd all the data goes to the same output file.

The first time through fork, there's no pending output, so that child wont write anything when it exists. The second time, there's a "0\n" pending which it will write when it exits, the next time, there's "0\n1\n" buffered, etc. The forked processes may not exit in the order they're created (they're asynchronous), hence your jumbled results.

Forks preserve open Files and Sockets, so one needs to be careful to mange them carefully.

You can probably fix this behavior by telling ruby to flush output on each write instead of buffering.

```
class Recorder
  def initialize(notifier, filename)
    notifier.add_observer(self)
    @save_file =  File.open(filename, 'w')
    @save_file.sync = true # don't buffer this file
    @i = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the above worked.  I edited your answer as the sync line made no difference, but the principle was correct and works using flush instead.

Comment: It's curious that IO#sync= didn't work for you. I tried the @save_file.sync = true with your code and it worked with ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux] and ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux]